# Unable to predict by loading pre-trained models(loadLayersModel) in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have trained and generated the files as described in [TensorFlow.js Readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/README.md)

but when i predict, it doesn't works

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1 id="p">Try Tensorflow</h1>
  <p>model.json</p><input type="file" id="upload-json" />
  <p>weight.bin</p><input type="file" id="upload-weights" />
  <button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      const uploadJSONInput = document.getElementById('upload-json');
      const uploadWeightsInput = document.getElementById('upload-weights');
      console.log('start');
      tf.tensor([
        [1, 2],
        [3, 4]
      ]).print(); //no issues umtill here

      const model = tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles(
        [uploadJSONInput.files[0], uploadWeightsInput.files[0]]
      )).then(() => {
        console.log('will print now');
        model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
      });
      console.log(model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print());

    }
  </script>
</div>
```

What should i change to make it predict?

[The trained files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dnrIa7veb39qRU3ZlTseV-4uqWJRNUGc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `model` variable is not known in the scope of the `.then(() => ...)` function. You either need to return the model to access it or use await/async syntax.

See the following working code sample which uses await/async syntax to load the model and predict the value:

```js
async function loadModel() {
  const uploadJSONInput = document.getElementById('upload-json');
  const uploadWeightsInput = document.getElementById('upload-weights');

  const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles(
    [uploadJSONInput.files[0], uploadWeightsInput.files[0]]
  ));
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
}
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', loadModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h1 id="p">Try Tensorflow</h1>
  <p>model.json</p><input type="file" id="upload-json" />
  <p>weight.bin</p><input type="file" id="upload-weights" />
  <button type="button" id="myBtn">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hello ,thanks this definitely gives a hint . but why is it that the model always predicts value of [[7.8631339],] ?  what i mean here is, that it should have tried predicting values that are close, to fit in the model y=2x-1(as per x and y data). now 2*5-1 should be close 9 ,definitely not 7.8

Comment: @ShariqAzim That's a very different question ;) I recommend opening another question regarding that problem and tagging it `machine-learning` as this is not about the implementation but about the model. You should also state what values you are expecting and how you trained the model. Hope that helps you :)